# Best way to read a text file line by line, taking each line and putting it into the code

Tags: java

First of all, I am but a lowly web-programmer so have very little experience with actual programming. 
I have been given a list of 30,000 urls and I am not going to waste my time clicking each one to check if they are valid - is there a way to read through the text file that they are in and have a program check each line?

The code I currently have is in java as really that's all I know so if there's a better language again, please let me know.
Here is what I have so far:

```
public class UrlCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        //Need to change this to make it read from text file
        try {
            InputStream inp = null;
            try {
                inp = url.openStream();
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
            if (inp != null) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how the urls distributed? can you post the sample `.txt file`?

Answer (score 2):

First you read the file line by line using a `BufferedReader` and check each line. Below code should work. It is upto you to decide what to do when you encounter an invalid URL. You could just print it as I showed or write to another file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.UnknownHostException;

public class UrlCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("_filename"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           if(checkUrl(line)) {
               System.out.println("URL " + line + " was OK");
           } else {
               System.out.println("URL " + line + " was not VALID"); //handle error as you like
           }
        }

        br.close();
    }

    private static boolean checkUrl(String pUrl) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(pUrl);
        //Need to change this to make it read from text file
        try {
            InputStream inp = null;

            try {
                inp = url.openStream();
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
                return false;
            }
            if (inp != null) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The `checkUrl` method can be simplified as below as well

```
private static boolean checkUrl(String pUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    InputStream inp = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(pUrl);
        inp = url.openStream();

        return inp != null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inp != null) {
                inp.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad that it helped (you could also select it as right answer if you are satisfied :-))

Answer (score 0):

You could just use httpURLConnection. If it is not valid you won't get anything back.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try{         
    URL myurl = new URL("http://www.myURL.com");        
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection(); 

    //Set request to header to reduce load 
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");         
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();        
    System.out.println("" + code); 
} catch {
//Handle invalid URL
}
```

Comment: My issue isn't checking if the url is valid or not, it's getting 30,000 urls into where the url is at the moment. The code I currently have returns if the url is valid or not well enough.

Comment: URL url = new URL (String containing url);

Comment: I am not getting "it's getting 30,000 urls into where the url is at the moment" this line, what do you mean, can you please explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your experience but a multi-threaded solution is possible here.  As you read through the text file store the urls in a thread-safe structure and allow a number of threads to go and attempt to open these connections.  This will make for a more efficient solution as it may take a while to test the 30000 urls while you are reading them in.

Check out a producer-consumer example if you are unsure:

http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UrlCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            //Open the Http connection
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //Get the http response code
            int responceCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responceCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) //if the http response code is 200 OK so the url is valid
            {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else //Else the url is not valid
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```